# Using nodemailer to send emails regularly

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, email, nodemailer

Hi I was wondering if anyone could provide some guidance for how I could go about implementing some functionality to set up scheduling with emailing using nodemailer.

Like Ideally I could schedule an email to send every day at 9am using nodemailer in a web app but I dont know where to begin. Right now I have set up my client side (in AngularJS) and service side code (nodeJS using nodemailer) to send the email the moment the user fills out a form and hits a send an email.

Or I would like to add an option to allow users to send an email in an hour

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may use some cron job tools like [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron)